# Slow update of one table when comparing multiple fields across two tables

Tags: mysql

The following query is timing out after 600 seconds.

```
update placed p
      ,Results r
  set p.position = r.position
  where p.competitor = r.competitor
    AND p.date = r.date 
    AND REPLACE(p.time,":","") = r.time;
```

The structure is as follows:

```
'CREATE TABLE `placed` (
  `idplaced` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` decimal(8,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `competitor` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field2` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field3` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field4` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field5` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field6` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field7` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field8` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field9` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field10` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field11` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field12` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field13` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field14` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field15` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field16` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field17` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field18` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field19` char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field20` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field21` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field22` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field23` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (`idplaced`),
  UNIQUE KEY `date_time_competitor_field18_combo` (`date`,`time`,`competitor`,`field18`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100688607 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `results` (
  `idresults` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` char(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `competitor` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field3` decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idresults`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6644 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The `PLACED` table has 65,000 records, the `RESULTS` table has 9,000 records.

I am assuming the solution involves a `JOIN` statement of some descript, and I have tried taking several suggestions from this site, but am simply not finding the answer I am looking for.  Simply put, I would be grateful for suggestions on this.  I can put up example tables / create table code if requried.

Comment: Instead of describing your tables/indexes in your own words, could you post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` for each table?

Comment: @MarkByers - yes, sorry, should have done that from the offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index cannot be used efficiently to perform the join because of your `REPLACE` operation. 
I'd suggest creating an index with the columns in the following slightly different order:

```
(date, competitor, time, position)
```

It may also help to add this index on both tables.

It would be even better if you could modify the data in the database so that the data in the `time` column was stored in the same format in both tables.

Comment: The `REPLACE` was indeed the killer.  For the record, `POSITION` was never in the index, but I did try a reorder (before removing the `REPLACE` but it did not change anything.  I was also unable to apply the same index to both tables due to table `RESULT` not having all of the fields in the `INDEX`.  Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'd better send us your full tables description, using

```
show create table
```

Second, you'd better use join syntax :

```
update placed p
  join Results r on r.competitor = p.competitor
   set p.position = r.position
 where p.date = r.date 
   AND REPLACE(p.time,":","") = r.time;
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I had tried this one, but it also timesout after 600 seconds.